# How to paste text in Inkscape without creating a new text block?

Tags: inkscape

In a text block in Inkscape I select some text, copy it, move up the box, and paste it. But it pastes a text box into or over my existing box - it doesn't actually paste the text into the box I'm in.

How do I do that please?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the text tool selected, highlight some text, and copy/cut it.

Then with the text tool still selected, position the cursor somewhere else, making sure it is actually inside the text box you are trying to paste into. It can sometimes be a little tricky.  You will know if you are in the text box because you will see the bounding boxes.

Example. Here I'm using Ctrl+X to cut, then Ctrl+V to paste

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm doing that. Oh well, thank you.